# jQuery custom content scroller horizontal issues with persian and responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mcustomscrollbar

I'm using this plugin for adding custom scrolling function into my web page. 
(http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/)
At some section I need a newspaper-like content/post with columns to be scrolled horizontally, but the problem :

1. Media-queries and responsiveness of the layout doesn't apply
2. Language of my content is RTL (Persian) I want the scrolling to start from right to left, but it naturally starts from left, so there's a huge space from left and we have to scroll to reach the original content.

I'd be grateful if I can get a solution from you guys :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Update. Is there any help?